# How to change default signature font in thunderbird 13.0.1 used in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, thunderbird

How to change default signature font in Thunderbird 13.0.1 used in Ubuntu?

I am able to setup my  signature but with default fonts, I want those default font to be changed in my signature.

also when I am forwarding any mail I am not getting any signature in that forwarded mail.

please help.

OS - Ubuntu, Thunderbird version 13.0.1
thanks.

Comment: How are you using Thunderbird 13.0.1 in Ubuntu? No official downstream [binary](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=thunderbird&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) or [source](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird) `thunderbird` packages for supported Ubuntu releases are major version 13, nor do such packages appear on the `old-releases` server (["t" for thunderbird](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/), ["m" for mozilla](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/)). Are you using upstream builds/sources? What Ubuntu release are you using?

Answer (score 6):

You can follow the instructions here:

http://www.ehow.com/how_8530736_change-default-signature-fonts-thunderbird.html

> 1. Launch Mozilla Thunderbird and click "Write" to open a new message. You won't be emailing anyone, but you can use the message writer to format your signature.
> 2. Type the text for the signature you wish to use. You can type anything you like, but remember it will automatically be appended to every email you send.
> 3. Press "Ctrl" and "A" to highlight all the signature text you just typed. Click "Format" from the toolbar at the top of the window. Use the various options to format your text. Click "Font" to select the font style to use, select "Size" to pick the font size and select "Style" to make your text bold or italicized.
> 4. Click "Insert" and click "HTML" when you have finished formatting your signature text. A window will open that contains your text with all of the alterations you made to it, written in HTML. Press "Ctrl" and "A" to select the HTML code and press "Ctrl" and "C" to copy it to the Windows clipboard. Click "Cancel" to close the HTML window and click the "X" on the "Write" window to close your message.
> 5. Select your email account from the list of "All Folders" on the left side of the Thunderbird window. Click "View settings for this account." Select your email address from the "Account Settings" window. Select "Use HTML" next to "Signature Text" and click the text box. Press "Ctrl" and "V" to paste the HTML code into the box. Click "OK" to finalize the change.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up an html signature. This is explained in this support article: https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/signatures

You should also update Thunderbird to its latest release, which is 17.0.2. Normally Ubuntu provide up-to-date version of Thunderbird, so I don't understand why you are still using this old version.